# One UITableView - Multiple DataSource, best design pattern?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, oop, cocoa-design-patterns

This seems like a typical problem, but I have a UITableView that has identical behavior for two separate data sources. What is the best way of going about designing the class hierarchy to have as little duplication and if/else conditions? The view controller is going to do the same exact thing to both data sources, they're just unique in their data set. Should I have the parent controller just set its data source/respective title?

The same issue is relevant as well when using a UISegmentControl for displaying two views with the same interfaces, but different data sources.

Answer (score 12):

Be careful with your terminology here. A UITableView has something called a `dataSource` but you seem to be referring, essentially, to two different sets of data.

In the case you're suggesting, in the table's `dataSource` (the object that adheres to the UITableViewDataSource protocol), I'd have three arrays.

- currentlyViewedArray
- datasetOneArray
- datasetTwoArray

In the dataSource methods, use the currentlyViewedArray as the source of the table's data.

Then, set the currentlyViewedArray to whichever array you want to view:

```
self.currentlyViewedArray = self.datasetOneArray;
[theTableView reloadData];
```

You can use the UISegmentedControl to switch between the two arrays.